# NoClassDefFound error with OrmliteSqliteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, ormlite

I have a class which extends OrmliteSqliteOpenHelper in order to provide a persistence module for an Android application.  The problem is, whenever I access this class from the test project in Eclipse, it throws a NoClassDefFound Exception.  The source code appears to be fine as the package is imported and Eclipse has no highlighting to indicate anything will go wrong, but it does.

Here's the kicker: not only does everything else in the project work fine when accessed from the test project, but when I move this file into the test project voila it works perfectly!  The issue is that it needs to be in the actual project in order for other components to make calls to it.  Has anyone ever encountered this error or have any idea where I might be going wrong?

The class path is set correctly as all the other classes work and the test project always has the main project added to its class path.  I also tried moving the OrmliteSqliteOpenHelper object to an inner class: this allowed the outer class to be visible and touched but as soon as it tried to instantiate the inner class the same error occurs.  Also, if I copy this file into both projects in the same package, an error occurs stating "class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation" whenever something in the main project tries to access this class.  Clearly, there is some difference in the way the class is being compiled/handled between the two projects.

I'm quite stumped :/  Thanks a ton for any assistance!

Comment: Kyle, which class get the NoClassDefFound exception?  The OrmliteSqliteOpenHelper base class or your subclass?  Can you post the trimmed down class hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Well friends, I seem to have hacked together a solution for this issue: 
I linked the entire 'src' folder from the main project into the one for the test project.  Now, when it goes searching for the particular package my file is located in, it finds the file in its own source tree first.  Hooray!

Why does this work? I haven't a clue, perhaps someone could enlighten us to that fact.
Does it work? For now...

Answer (score 0):

There is how I fix the problem:

- Remove OrmLite from Build Path of the test project.
- Export them from the main project.